# execute function not work it get error in window array problem face

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
          if(isset($_POST["singup"])){

            $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $birthday = $_POST["birthday"];
            $gender = $_POST["gender"];
            $country = $_POST["country"];
            $tel = $_POST["countrycode"];
            $phone = $_POST["phone"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];
            $repassword = $_POST["repassword"];
            $agree = $_POST["agree"];

            // echo $fullname . " " . $email . " " . $birthday . " " . $gender . " " . $country . " " . $tel . " " . $phone . " " . $password . " " . $repassword . " " . $agree;


            $sql ="INSERT INTO accounts (fullname, email, birthday, gender, country, countrycode, phone, password, repassword, agree) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmtinsert = $db->prepare($sql);
            $result = $stmtinsert->execute([$fullname, $email, $birthday, $gender, $country, $tel, $phone, $password, $repassword, $agree]);
            if($result){
              echo "done";
            }else{
              echo "wrong";
            }
          }
   ?>
```

erro

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\localhost\htdocs\test\index.php:1043 Stack trace: #0 C:\localhost\htdocs\test\index.php(1043): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\localhost\htdocs\test\index.php on line 1043

1043 line is

```
$result = $stmtinsert->execute([$fullname, $email, $birthday, $gender, $country, $tel, $phone, $password, $repassword, $agree]);
```

useing msql php is

```
<?php 
     $db_user = "root"; 
     $db_pass = ""; 
     $db_name = "useraccounts"; 
     $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass); 
      $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
?>
```

and mql table is also created and add all col. and name but 1 is for id

Answer (score 1):

You have ten columns and values and only nine place holders

So the error message clearly states, so add a placeholder

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO accounts (fullname, email, birthday, gender, country, countrycode, phone, password, repassword, agree) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to understand the error message:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

The "bound variables" are the array of variables you pass to the execute method, each of which needs to correspond to a "?" placeholder. The "tokens" are therefore presumably those "?" placeholders.

So let's count the two:

> VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

That's nine placeholders.

> [$fullname, $email, $birthday, $gender, $country, $tel, $phone, $password, $repassword, $agree]

That's ten variables. So the error is correct: they don't match up.

We can also work out which is right:

> INSERT INTO accounts (fullname, email, birthday, gender, country, countrycode, phone, password, repassword, agree)

That's ten columns. So quite simply, you're missing a "?".

I hope this provides a helpful example of how to debug error messages yourself in future.